# One certificate for development and distribution for all app in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, ad-hoc-distribution

Previously I've certificate that I could used to development and distribution for all of my app. I don't required any other certificate for development or distribution. But accidently I removed the certificate from my keychain. Now whenever I try to create a certificate to develop and distribute certificate it doesn't allow me to do this.

Is there any way to create a certificate that will allow me to develop and distribute all of my app with one certificate

Comment: Revoke the certificate from the development team. Create a new certificate request and upload it to the appstore, select Apple Development and you can download the cert now and install it in your keychain for use.

Comment: will it work for all app in both development and distribution?